# get images with wordpress get_attached_media()

Tags: php, wordpress

Can somebody please tell me how I can use `get_attached_media( 'img', postID );` to
get all the attached images from the post and then display the images?

I need the code that goes after it to get the images.

I'm using this function directly within a page with phpexec plugin installed

my gratitude in advance

Comment: Used this function wp_get_attachment_image();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

get_attached_media returns `WP_Post` type data

```
<?php 
$images = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
foreach($images as $image) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'full'); ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

you can replace the word 'full' with the size of the image you would like either based on the standard sizes or potentially ones you've added to your theme's `function.php`

if you are looking for items other than 'image' you should use `wp_get_attachment_url` instead of `wp_get_attachment_image_url`

Comment: inside that foreach loop you are dealing with the image itself and its associated `WP_Post` data so you would `echo $image->XXX` where XXX is anything from this list: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

Comment: *Heads up!* The `get_attched_media` function only returns images that are 'attached' to that post. This does not necessarily mean it is all image in that post. Rather, an image becomes attached to the first post it is published in. 
Therefore, using the same image in a later post will not include that image in the array when calling `get_attached_media( $post )`.

Comment: @Herzlin please keep in mind this post is more than 6 years old, WP has almost certain changed since this code was written. If you'd like to provide a more recent answer to the question, you are strongly encouraged to :)

Comment: @haxxxton hi, i´m sure yours was working before, sorry for my dry message, 
the answer provided by Rick Hellewell is currently working.

Answer (score 4):

I believed this is the correct answer:

```
$images = get_attached_media('image' ); // get attached media
foreach ($images as $image) {  
    $ximage =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'medium');
    echo '<img src="' .$ximage[0] . '" />';
}
```

The statement in another answer

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'full')[0];
```

is not syntatically correct and will produce an error.

You can see the values of the array that are available with a `var_dump($images)`.

Comment: valid by December 2020 , I have verified it.

Answer (score 3):

[wp_get_attachment_image_src()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) actually returns an array so to retrieve the URL as you are doing in the above example you would need:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID,'full')[0]; ?>" />
```

For reference parameters `[1]` and `[2]` are also the width and height of the created image and you should check for false in case no image is found

Also the last comment in the above answer is incorrect - it should be 'wp_get_attachment_image_src' as per the example not 'wp_get_attachment_image_url'