# WP query retrieve the src of the attached image

Tags: json, wordpress

I'm encoding in JSON a bunch of data from a WP Query:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category' => 6,
    'meta_key' => 'custom_total_hits',
    'tag' => 'indie-pop',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-40 days')) 
    )
); 

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$posts = $query->get_posts();   

foreach( $posts as $post ) {    
    $output[] = array( 
    'id' => $post->ID, 
    'title' => $post->post_title, 
    'count' => $post->custom_total_hits, 
    'soundcloud_url' => $post->soundcloud_song, 
    'soundcloud_id' => $post->soundcloud_ids, 
    'link' => get_permalink($post), 

);
 }     

echo json_encode($output);
```

I would like to display in my JSON a key corrisponding to the src of the medium size of the attached image. If I use `'images' => get_attached_media('image', $post->ID)` it retrives an array of multiple data which I can not access since I don't know the ID of the attached image when I process the data of my JSON. How can I do to retrieve a first level key - value where the value is the src  of the attached image?

Comment: See this article -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22715522/get-images-with-wordpress-get-attached-media

Comment: @htmlbrewery well this is not helping, I need to encode a `value - key` data in json

Comment: What You like to get from `get_attached_media`(one imge or images) ?

Comment: just one image, or (better) three pair of `key : value`  like this: `"image_thumbnail" : "http..."` , `"image_medium" : "http..."` , `"image_full" : "http..."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`get_post_thumbnail_id`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_post_thumbnail_id) : Get post thumbnail ID

[**`wp_get_attachment_url`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) : Get attachment URL by attachment id

```
'images' => parse_url( wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ) );
```

Would you please try above code?

Comment: This is quite a good solution, it returns an array of scheme, host and path of the image, like this: "images":{"scheme":"https","host":"www.....com","path":"\/wp-content\/uploads\/2017\/04\/hers.png"}

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
$images = array();
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );

foreach (get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $size) {
    $images[$size] = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, $size);
}


//end

'images' => $images // type_of_size => image_url
```